# Alterar dados de um metodo do Slick em versão mobile - Slick

Tags: javascript, front-end

Estou fazendo alguns alterações em um determinado site, porem, eu fiquei emperrado.
Esse site ele possui o **slide Slick**, percebi que toda resolução menor que 480 as setas do slide some, ou seja, ha um breakpoint.

**o meu objetivo é  ativar essas seta para versão mobile**

como posso alterar configurações do slickede forma indireta(não tenho acesso ao código, apenas adicionar novos codigos).

```js
var i = Number($("[data-produtos-linha]").attr("data-produtos-linha"));
    if ($("img[data-imagem-caminho]").length && $("body").on("mouseover", ".listagem-item", function() {
            var b = $(this).find("img[data-imagem-caminho]");
            b.hasClass("hover") || (b.addClass("hover"), b.after('<img src="' + b.data("imagem-caminho") + '" class="imagem-zoom">'))
        }), i) new LazyLoad2({
        threshold: 120,
        elements_selector: ".slick-product",
        callback_enter: function(b) {
            $(b).slick({
                infinite: !0,
                lazyLoad: "ondemand",
                speed: 300,
                slidesToShow: i,
                slidesToScroll: 1,
                responsive: [{
                    breakpoint: 1024,
                    settings: {
                        slidesToShow: i - 1,
                        slidesToScroll: i - 1,
                        infinite: !0
                    }
                }, {
                    breakpoint: 480,
                    settings: {
                        arrows: !1,
                        slidesToShow: 2,
                        slidesToScroll: 2,
                        infinite: !0
                    }
                }]
            })
        }
    })
```

SEGUE O LINK DO CODIGO COMPLETO DO JS com slick
https://cdn.awsli.com.br/temasv2/1528/__theme_custom.js?v=1604067677

versao mobile
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

versao desktop[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: No seu breakpoint de 480, em configurações, os arrows invés de ``!1`` não seria ``true`` ou ``!0`` ?